# unable to apply glow effect at the progress bar

Tags: android, user-interface, progress-bar

I am trying to apply the glow effect at the progress bar . I am using png image for displaying the glow effect but it is not moving as loading proceeds .Any help would be appreciated . Thanks.

mydrawable.xml :-

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
      >
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="20dip"
               />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#434343"
                    android:centerColor="#ffffff"

                   android:endColor="#434343"
                    android:angle="270"


            />
            <!-- gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                    android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ff747674"
                    android:angle="270"
                     android:centerColor="#0040F8"
                     android:endColor="#00F810"
          /-->

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">

        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="20dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#F80070"
                        android:centerColor="#00F810"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#F88000"
                        android:angle="270"

                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

 <item android:id="@android:id/progress">

        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="20dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#F80070"
                        android:centerColor="#FFFF00"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#F88000"
                        android:angle="0"

                />
            </shape>
        </clip>

    </item>

 <item >
    <bitmap

        android:antialias="true"
        android:gravity="right|bottom|fill_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/glow1" />
</item>   

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the drawable in your xml like this:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
               android:drawable="@drawable/glow1" />
    </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Through code you can do like this.

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(getShapeWithGlow(
                progressBar,
                progressBar.getResources().getColor(R.color.gradient_white, null),
                progressBar.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white, null)));



public static Drawable getShapeWithGlow(View view, int backgroundColor, int glowColor) {

    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();

    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(backgroundColor);

    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShadowLayer(13, 0, 0,
            glowColor); //      To create shadow like background glow

    view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); // To display the glow need to set Layer type.

    InsetDrawable insetDrawable = new InsetDrawable(shapeDrawable, 0, 10, 0, 10);

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{insetDrawable, shapeDrawable});
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 0, 8, 0, 8);

    ClipDrawable drawableProgress = new ClipDrawable(layerDrawable, Gravity.START, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);

    return drawableProgress;

}
```